# How I can count with GROUP BY and condition in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table:

[image: Signups group by _legajo]

And I need:

[image: Indexes]

Where:

- Complete have all records with same `_legajo and _count > 0`
- Zero have all records with `same_legajo and _count = 0`
- Track have all records with same `_legajo`, `some records with _count 0 and some with _count >`

My table is 20k records

I working on `PHP` and `MySQL`

some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could first select `MIN` and `MAX` for each `_legajo`:

```
SELECT _legajo, MIN(_count), MAX(_count)
  FROM signups
  GROUP BY _legajo;
```

If `MAX` is zero, then it naturally belongs to the `zero` category. If `MIN` is larger than zero then it belongs to `complete` category (`MAX` is naturally larger than zero then). If `MIN` is zero and `MAX` isn't, then it's in `track`.

Then you can just use `SUM` to determine the counts with the conditions:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN min>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as complete,
  SUM(CASE WHEN max=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as zero,
  SUM(CASE WHEN min=0 AND max>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as track
FROM (SELECT _legajo, MIN(_count), MAX(_count)
  FROM signups
  GROUP BY _legajo) a;
```